# Главные члены в придаточном предложении: "... что бы все это значило"

Tags: сказуемые, подлежащее

Как бы вы выделили главные члены предложения в данном **придаточном**:

> ... что бы (не союз чтобы!) все это значило.

Comment: @katherin155, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Мне думается, что здесь подлежащее "это", а сказуемое "что значило бы" (интерпретация: это (предмет речи) значило что (является тем-то))

Answer (score 1):

*все это* - подлежащее.

*что значило бы* - сказуемое.

*всё это* - слитное сочетание, обозначающее единое множество, *бы* - частица-показатель наклонения, *значило* - глагол-связка в составном именном сказуемом.

Answer (score 0):

Всё это - подлежащее, значило бы - сказуемое, что - дополнение.

Можно сравнить: это значило бы (что?), что вопрос уже решен.

Уважаемые друзья!

Извините, при ответе я невнимательно прочитала вопрос, пропустив слово «придаточное». Получается, что мы рассматриваем предложение следующего вида: Я не понимаю, что бы всё это значило. Это ссп с придаточным изъяснительным, при этом «что» является **союзным словом**, и мы решаем, каким членом предложения он является в придаточном. И знаете, мне по-прежнему кажется, что это дополнение. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вы считаете его сказуемым, разве дополнение не может стоять на первом месте.

Answer (score 0):

***Ответ Граммы.ру***

> В том примере, который Вы приводите, "что (бы)" является скорее 
>   дополнением. Глагол "значит" выступает в качестве связки в 
>   биинфинитивном предложении, то есть в предложении, где "значит" 
>   связывает два инфинитива ("Понять значит простить";-). В предложениях, где
>    "значит" соединяет два существительных, этот глагол является более или 
>   менее полнозначным.